How to customize paths in VSCode
I am trying to do a simple gRPC client-server application on c++.I've installed and build gRPC, but when i try to make import from it, I face an error 'No such file or directory'. I supposed it happens because incorrect path in vs settings and try to change them but without success.
I try build with command:
g++ -std=c++11 server.cpp service.grpc.pb.cc service.pb.cc -lgrpc++ -lprotobuf -pthread -o server

My 'file-tree':
gRPCLaba
├── .vscode
│   ├── settings.json
│   └── c_cpp_properties.json
├── grpc
│   └── a lot of files and dirs...
├── client.cpp
├── server.cpp
├── service.grpc.pb.cc
├── service.grpc.pb.h
├── service.pb.cc
├── service.pb.h
└── service.proto

Imports in server.cpp
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "service.grpc.pb.h"

Imports in service.grpc.pb.h
#include <grpc/impl/codegen/port_platform.h> 
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_generic_service.h> 
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_stream.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_unary_call.h>
// etc

my settings.json
{
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "/home/danil/gRPCLaba/grpc"
}

my c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
       {
          "name": "Linux",
          "includePath": [
             "${workspaceFolder}/**"
          "defines": [],
          "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
          "cStandard": "c17",
          "cppStandard": "gnu++17", "intelliSenseMode" : "linux-gcc-x64"
       }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I've tried to add full path to dir in "includePath" c_cpp_properties.json with grpcpp in my case it was /home/danil/gRPCLaba/grpc/include.

How are you building the code? c_cpp_properties.json only controls intellisense

I use command: g++ -std=c++11 server.cpp service.grpc.pb.cc service.pb.cc -lgrpc++ -lprotobuf -pthread -o server

Please [edit] that into your question. It's that command that you need to pass the include directory to

your JSON is invalid. fix it.

And how to fix it?

@super-starball-ultra the json isn't really relevant to the question

@AlanBirtles it could be if it's an intellisense error rather than a build error.
